# Reason why window.print() javascript doesnt get previewed in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a link in a page which I am using for print the page using window.print(),
I want reason why this is not showing preview in Chrome until unless I Add return false in after window.print().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return false;` prevents the default action taken by the browser. In a link's case, it prevents the link from being followed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```